# Yii search difficulty

Tags: php, mysql, search, yii, criteria

Lets say we have table which has column named `number` (data type `varchar`) which consists of cell phone numbers. Phone numbers are fixed size  - 10 digits. What I want to do is, to search for digits in exact positions. Like:

When I send: xxx xxx xx xx it will return all numberrs

When I send: 223 2x5 xx xx it will return numbers only matching this pattern

How to achieve this using `CDbcriteria` in Yii framework?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say user entered numbers and you have `$_POST["num"]` variable that gets all numbers

```
            $number = "";
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
                if (is_numeric($_POST["num"][$counter]))
                    $number .= $_POST["num"][$counter];
                else
                    $number .= "%";
            }
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "number LIKE :number";
            $criteria->params = array(':number' => $number);
            ....
```

This must help you

Comment: What about using `preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '%', $_POST["num"], -1, $count)` instead of the for loop? 223 2x5 xx xx returns '223%2%5%' and xxx xxx xx xx return '%'.

Comment: Part of the specification was "exact position".  Since `%` matches any number of characters, it will not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'x', use '_' and remove the spaces., then do the `LIKE` as suggested.

Looking for `223 2x5 xx xx`, use `number LIKE "2232_5____"`.

If necessary, you could do

```
number LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE("223 2x5 xx xx", 'x', '_'), ' ', '')
```

Here's a test:

```
mysql> select '2232958765' LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE("223 2x5 xx xx", 'x', '_'), ' ', '');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| '2232958765' LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE("223 2x5 xx xx", 'x', '_'), ' ', '') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```